# GUI Button click effect in unity3d

Tags: c#, button, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a button in a scene.

Can say ButtonA.

While clicking another button a popup comes.

There is a button in popup also. Say popupbutton.

While clicking on popupbutton, ButtonA works.

How can i escape from this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GUI handling is especially weak in Unity3D. A solution i've been using is to write a class that handles the input in all active buttons in a scene and maintains a Queue (back to front) of them. When an input is received on a position, it sends the input event to only the top layer of the active buttons.